# Templates does not exist

Tags: django, django-views

How to specify a path to base_site.html that would have views the blog saw it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQNnQ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: In addition to the above I would recommend you to take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You have to do 2 things

1. Edit the templates settings to include templates folder
2. Call the template by ‘admin/base_site.html’

Answer (score 0):

First of all add this in your settings.py
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR / "templates")]
For Example:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR / "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Now change the path or just paste this, and let me know..
`return render(request, "admin/base_site.html", {"tasks":tasks})`